# Autocomplete Select will redirect to new url

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, autocomplete

I am using the `.autocomplete` from jQuery-ui. I would like to search through my ajax URL and return whatever is in my database. When I click on the autocomplete suggestions, I want it to redirect to another URL with whatever item I click to be a New Board and displaying on that page as a new board.

I have seen some questions that ask for what I want, but I can't seem to get the redirect going. My python view only GET's the `'q'` after I click on the item and it fills the input with the name then I press 'Enter' and then it'll redirect.

I am using Django, and inserting all the js/jQuery code inside of my templates for now.

views.py

```
def search_boards(request):
  boards = Board.objects.all()
  query = request.GET.get('q')
  if query:
    print(query)
    boards = boards.filter(name__icontains=query).distinct()
    if boards:
      print(len(boards))
      board = Board(name=[b.name for b in boards][0]
      board.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
  return render(request, 'search_boards.html', {'boards': boards})


def ajax_search_boards(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        search_text = request.GET.get('term', '')
        boards = Board.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_text)
        return JsonResponse([{'id': i, 'value': v.name} for i, v in enumerate(boards)], safe=False)
```

search_boards.html

```
<body>
  <form method="GET" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
    <input name="q" id="autocomplete">
  </form>

  <script>
    $("input[name='q']").autocomplete({
      source: '/ajax_search_boards/',
      select: function(e, ui) {
        if ($("input[name='q']").val(ui.item.value)) {
          $("#autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);
          $("#autocomplete").submit();
          location.href = '/'; // this will redirect me, but it wont redirect me with a new board created. 
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: what issue are you facing ?

Comment: @navyad I want the Redirect to occur immediately after I click on the suggested list item, but it only happens after I choose the item and then press enter.